# What does "Warmer" mean in this conversation?

Tags: meaning

This is a conversation from ["RWBY"](https://rwby.fandom.com/wiki/Volume_6) volume 6:

A: I wouldn't exactly call us "friends".
B: Acquaintances?
A: Not quite.
B: Colleagues?
A: **Warmer.**
B: Enemies?
A: That's the one.

Does "warmer" mean "our relationship is warmer than just colleagues", or does it mean "we're not as warm as colleagues"?

Comment: No. "Warmer" is a short form of "you are getting warmer". It's an expression which means "you are getting closer to the truth".

Answer (score 6):

Conversant A is being ***facetious*** when he says *I wouldn't exactly call us "friends"*. That's like saying *I wouldn't exactly say a Rolls Royce is a "cheap" car*.

When A says "colleagues" is "warmer" than "acquaintances", he's just playing [the game of "hot / cold"](https://www.considerable.com/entertainment/games/hot-and-cold/) as responses to guesses (a bit like ["20 questions"](https://psycatgames.com/magazine/conversation-starters/20-questions-game/)). He doesn't mean the *relationship* is "warmer" - he (facetiously) means *Your second guess is **closer to the true description** than your first guess*.

Except not everyone would agree that "colleague" is "nearer in meaning" to "enemy" than "acquaintance" is anyway.

---

TL;DR:

*I wouldn't exactly say it's X* can be a facetious way of saying *It's **the complete opposite** of X*